# query relational tag data, grouping by a different metric

Tags: query, group-by, sqlite

Suppose I have the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tag_group (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
);


CREATE TABLE tag (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  tag_group_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_group_id) REFERENCES tag_group(id);
);

CREATE TABLE media (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  file TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE media_tag (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  media_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tag(id)
  FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES media(id)
)
```

Essentially this is a database with media (files) that have tags attached to them. Tags in the system would look like this:

```
|   tag_group  |          tag |
|--------------|--------------|
| 'instrument' |     'guitar' |
|      'genre' |        'pop' |
|     'artist' | 'billy_joel' |
```

Retrieving media based on a tag query would look like this:

```sql
-- assume the query is something like "get me all the media for 'guns_n_roses', 'rock', 'guitar'"
SELECT media.* FROM media
INNER JOIN media_tag ON media_id = media.id
WHERE tag_id IN (1, 3, 5)
GROUP BY tag_id
HAVING COUNT(tag_id) >= 3
```

But, assume I want to get some more holistic info about whats in the database. How would I perform a query that filters using the same tag search (e.g. 'guns_n_roses', 'rock', 'guitar') and then group the rows based on tag group? E.g. the resulting data would look something like this:

```
|   tag_group  |  media_count  |
|--------------|---------------|
| 'instrument' |            7  |
|      'genre' |           19  |
|     'artist' |           40  |
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the closest I can get, but this query seems like it would have pretty poor performance

```sql
SELECT tag_group.name AS tag_group, COUNT(media.id) AS media_count FROM media
INNER JOIN media_tag ON media_id = media.id
INNER JOIN tag ON tag_id = tag.id
INNER JOIN tag_group ON tag_group_id = tag_group.id
WHERE media.id IN (
  SELECT id FROM media
  INNER JOIN media_tag ON media_id = media.id
  WHERE tag_id IN (1, 3, 5)
  GROUP BY tag_id
  HAVING COUNT(tag_id) >= 3
)
GROUP BY tag_group_id
```

It does appear to return the data that I want to see, but wouldn't this cause a lot of extra loops?

[edit] here is the query plan generated from the above statement. It appears that we duplicate work selecting from `media` using primary key, but that is the extent of duplicated work I see. Is this the best I can do? I would be curious if theres a smarter way to write my schemas/query.

```
|--SEARCH TABLE media USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
|--LIST SUBQUERY 1
|  |--SEARCH TABLE media_tag USING COVERING INDEX media_tag (tag_id=?)
|  `--SEARCH TABLE media USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE media_tag USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_media_tag_1 (media_id=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE tag USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
|--SEARCH TABLE tag_group USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
`--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```